# Matlab String Conversion to Array

Tags: string, matlab, split, octave

I got a string array of the format

```
sLine = 
{
   [1,1] = 13-Jul-16,10.46,100.63,15.7,54.4,55656465
   [1,2] = 12-Jul-16,10.47,100.64,15.7,54.4,55656465
   [1,3] = 11-Jul-16,10.48,100.65,15.7,54.4,55656465
   [1,4] = 10-Jul-16,10.49,100.66,15.7,54.4,55656465
}
```

In which each element is a string ("13-Jul-16,10.46,100.63,15.7,54.4,55656465" is a string).

I need to convert this to 6 vectors, something like

```
[a b c d e f] = ...
```

such a way, for example, for the 1st column, it would be

```
a = [13-Jul-16;12-Jul-16;11-Jul-16;10-Jul-16]
```

I tried to use cell2mat function, but for some reason it does not separate the fields into matrix elements, but it concatenates the whole string into something like

```
cell2mat(sLine)
ans = 
     13-Jul-16,10.46,100.63,15.7,54.4,5565646512-Jul-16,10.47,100.64,15.7,54.4,5565646511-Jul-16,10.48,100.65,15.7,54.4,5565646510-Jul-16,10.49,100.66,15.7,54.4,55656465
```

So, how can I solve this?

**Update**

I got the sLine matrix following the steps

```
pFile = urlread('http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=BVMF:PETR4&num=365&output=csv');
sLine = strsplit(pFile,'\n');
sLine(:,1)=[];
```

**Update**

Thanks to @Suever I could get now the column dates. So the updated last version of the code is

```
pFile = urlread('http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=BVMF:PETR4&num=365&output=csv');
pFile=strtrim(pFile);
sLine = strsplit(pFile,'\n');
sLine(:,1)=[];

split_values = regexp(sLine, ',', 'split');

values =  cat(1, split_values{:});
values(:,1)
```

Comment: you cannot use `cell2mat` because a mat (numerical matrix) cannot contain strings. so you will need to use cell Arrays. The function you are looking for is `strsplit`

Comment: I tried strsplit before, but no success. Anyway I need to convert that string into numeric values, to put each numeric column in a separate vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is all strings, therefore you will need to do some string manipulation rather than using `cell2mat`.

You will want to split each element at the `,`characters and then concatenate the result together.

```
sLine = {'13-Jul-16,10.46,100.63,15.7,54.4,55656465',
         '12-Jul-16,10.47,100.64,15.7,54.4,55656465',
         '11-Jul-16,10.48,100.65,15.7,54.4,55656465',
         '10-Jul-16,10.49,100.66,15.7,54.4,55656465'};

split_values = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x, ','), sLine, 'uniformoutput', 0);
values = cat(1, split_values{:});

values(:,1)

%   {
%     [1,1] = 13-Jul-16
%     [2,1] = 12-Jul-16
%     [3,1] = 11-Jul-16
%     [4,1] = 10-Jul-16
%   }
```

If you want it to be more concise, we can just use `regexp` to split it up instead of `strsplit` since it can accept a cell array as input.

```
split_values = regexp(sLine, ',', 'split');
values =  cat(1, split_values{:});
```

**Update**

The issue with the code that you've posted is that there is a trailing newline in the input and when you split on newlines the last element of your `sLine` cell array is empty causing your issues. You'll want to use `strtrim` on `pFile` before creating the cell array to remove trailing newlines.

```
sLine = strsplit(strtrim(pFile), '\n');
sLine(:,1) = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. In my case there were a dimension mismatch in the cat call, and I realized that my sLine is a transposed of yours. But even transposing it does not fix the mismatch. I updated the post with the exact steps to get my sLine matrix, it should be a small detail I am not seeing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rego Updated with a description of the reason you're having issues

Comment: Great, this way it has fixed the mismatch, so the column dates is correct. But I am trying to get the other columns using bO     =  cat(2, split_values{:}); and the result seems not be correct.

Comment: Why are you using the second dimension instead of the first?

Comment: bDates = cat(1, split_values{:}); get the first column, right? So I thought bO = cat(2, split_values{:}) gets the second column, bH = cat(3, split_values{:}) gets the third column, and so on?

Comment: For example, 13-Jul-16,10.46,100.63,15.7,54.4,55656465 means: 13-Jul-16 is a final date, 10.46 is a price type O, 100.63 is a price type H, etc. I should get a vector with all dates (which we got from  bDates = cat(1, split_values{:}) ) and other vectors, each one with the other data types.

Comment: @Rego To access the columns, you'll use `values(:,1), values(:,2)`, etc.

Comment: @Suever Wow thank you very much!! It worked as you said. Your help has been much appreciated.